# ADO - How do I call different parameters for a script depending on the context? / RUN THE SAME SCRIPT w/Dynamic Parameters according to the context

Tags: json, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-automation

AZURE ADO
I am working currently on a script to automate clean up unused storage accounts from Azure. This script would run on a Runbook. There are 4  subscriptions specifically created to contain storage accounts for each tenant, LAB and PRD, 2 each. So what I need is that THE SAME SCRIPT automatically runs with the subscription that corresponds to the Tenant that it belongs. There are 2 subscriptions for DEV and 2 for PRD. I would need to create an array for calling both of them at the same time depending on the context. I don't know how exactly I should parametrize the Subscription that will be called. Should I create a different file .json file with all the parameters? Note that also the same script should run at different times according to the tenant. That's why I created a schedule for LAB (THAT SHOULD RUN THE SCRIPT WITH THE BOTH LAB SUBS) and another Schedule for PRD (THAT SHOULD RUN THE SCRIPT WITH THE BOTH LAB SUBS)

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$SubscriptionFL
    )
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
```

I don't know how exactly I should proceed with this. The script itself works perfectly and does what's needed. My problem is that I'm pretty new in this and I'm figuring out stuff. I don't know how to make the script dynamic and be the most generic it can be, so that we would run the same script with different variables according to the context (LAB or PRD)

Comment: Are you trying to use Azure DevOps pipeline to achieve this? Have you tried using if expression? You could find samples in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#use-parameters-to-determine-what-steps-run). You can use service connection to authenticate different subscriptions and use [azure powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-powershell-v5?view=azure-pipelines) to run the runbook.

Comment: Is there any update for this issue? Have you checked my suggestion, does it work on your side?